# Blueimp Gallery Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been searching around and trying to find an answer to Blueimp not working...

This is heavily frustrating, and this is a school team website, and I kind of want it done very soon.

Here is the snippet of my code:

```
<!-- Images -->
    <div id="links">
        <a href="1.jpg" title="Banana">
            <img src="1.jpg" alt="Banana">
        </a>
        <a href="2.jpg" title="Apple">
            <img src="2.jpg" alt="Apple">
        </a>
    </div>

    <!-- Photo Gallery Courtesy of Blueimp -->
    <div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery blueimp-gallery-controls">
        <div class="slides"></div>
        <h3 class="title"></h3>
        <a class="prev">‹</a>
        <a class="next">›</a>
        <a class="close">×</a>
        <a class="play-pause"></a>
        <ol class="indicator"></ol>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("links").onclick=function(e){e=e||window.event;var t=e.target||e.srcElement,n=t.src?t.parentNode:t,r={index:n,event:e},i=this.getElementsByTagName("a");blueimp.Gallery(i,r)}</script>
```

These are the references in my head section:

```
<!-- Styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/animate.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/blueimp-gallery.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap-image-gallery.min.css" />
```

These are the JS references at the bottom of the document:

```
<!-- JS at bottom for faster load -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/menu_jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/bootstrap-image-gallery.min.js"></script>
```

It would be very kind if someone could tell me what is wrong? Personally, the documentation seems very vague, and this seems like a great product. I will now describe what I'm getting.

I'm getting the images, all right, but they aren't resized and quite large... It looks nothing like a gallery. I can click on the images, however, it just darkens the page like it's supposed to but no image gallery sliding fancy stuff.

So, is there a better gallery system or better tutorials, maybe even better, someone who can teach me exactly how to do this?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

include atribute **data-gallery** in a

Example:

```
<div id="links">
    <a href="1.jpg" title="Banana" data-gallery>
        <img src="1.jpg" alt="Banana">
    </a>
    <a href="2.jpg" title="Apple" data-gallery>
        <img src="2.jpg" alt="Apple">
    </a>
</div>
```